# JavaScript pre-allocated array Uncaught RangeError: Invalid Array Length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a small loop of code which is throwing Uncaught RangeError: Invalid Array Length

I was able to reproduce it with just this in the Google Chrome console

```
const COUNT = 100_000_000;
const xValues = new Array(COUNT);
const yValues = new Array(COUNT);
for (let i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
    xValues[i] = i;
    yValues[i] = Math.sin(i * 0.000001);
}
console.log(`count: ${yValues.length}`);
```

Here's the output in developer console

[image]

As far as I know the maximum array size in Javascript is 2^32-1? There should be enough memory to allocate here and the index i is never negative or outside the bounds of the array as far as I can see.

Curiously enough, if I use this code, there is no crash

```
const COUNT = 100_000_000;
const xValues = new Array(COUNT);
const yValues = new Array(COUNT);
for (let i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
    xValues[i] = i;
    yValues[i] = i;
}
console.log(`count: ${yValues.length}`);
```

[image]

The value assigned to yValues[i] never goes outiside of the range -1, +1 so I can't see this as a number out of range problem either.

Anyone shed any light on this?

**EDIT: Update**

Another scenario that doesn't work. Computing a random walk.

```
    const count = 100_000_000;
    const xValues = new Array(COUNT);
    const yValues = new Array(COUNT);
    let prevYValue = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        const curYValue = Math.random() - .5;

        xValues[i] = i;
        yValues[i] = prevYValue + curYValue;

        prevYValue += curYValue;
    }
```

This one throws as well! But

```
    yValues[i] = i
```

is fine ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**EDIT: Update 2**

Can now confirm this is browser specific, if you run the same test in firefox it works, but the browser asks you to wait.

Suspect the exception `Uncaught RangeError` is a badly reported timeout?

Comment: Interesting! It fails when `i` reaches 5,592,406 FYI (on my machine at least).

Comment: Chrome and Edge break both on the `Math.sin()` row when `i === 5592406`. If you start at `5592406` it breaks on `11184812` or `(5592406 * 2)`, and the same for `(5592406 * 3)` ...

Comment: `yValues[5592406] = Math.sin(5592406 * 0.000001)` alone passes, so the RangeError does _not_ seem to relate _only_ to the number of indexes, but also somehow to the content being stored in the array? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_array_length) doesn't make this behaviour explicit IMHO.

Comment: Strange isn't it! I tried other combinations. If I tried to calculate a random walk in the loop it would also crash, but yValues[i] = i is fine...

Comment: This may be a result of a heuristics that tries to check whether there is an infinite loop; after 5'592'406 iterations it gives up and throws a `RangeError`?

Comment: Strangely, reducing the count to 10_000_000 works and 5,592,406 is passed without issue. You've given me an idea though. Could it be a timeout by the browser? Math.sin() 100M times is pretty computationally expensive

Comment: Might be the case. What happens if each iteration does _more_ computationally expensive stuff?

Comment: "_Suspect the exception `Uncaught RangeError` is a badly reported timeout?_" Looks like a plain bug to me. The JS engine does all kinds of optimizations for heavy computations. Wouldn't surprise me if something went wrong there.

Comment: It is not related to computation. You get the same with just one array, and assigning a float to it, like `0.5`. The difference in behaviour is clearly linked to the internal data type that is used for the array elements: either 32-bit integers or floats. See the difference in assigning `1e9` (is a 32-bit integer) or `1e10` (not a 32-bit integer). It is not related to calling `Math.random` or `Math.sin`.

Comment: :O The mystery deepens

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry

Comment: Interestingly, this works in Node (at least Node 12)

Comment: Done, reported as a possible Chromium bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275993

Comment: Apparently, similar Array issues have existed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373153. Removing one zero or wrapping it in a Promise resulted in the block executing without error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real reason is in V8 memory optimization. When you store integers - it stores the 32 bit number in place, But when you store double-number - it is stored differently (as an object) - so `yValues` array contains the reference but the actual value stored in heap. So in your example you just used all heap memory. To see the limit, use: `console.memory` and you'll see something like this:

```
MemoryInfo {
totalJSHeapSize: 10000000, 
usedJSHeapSize: 10000000, 
jsHeapSizeLimit: 3760000000}
```

In my browser it is `3_760_000_000`

The object on heap takes 50+ bytes, so my limit somewhere around 69_000_000 floating point numbers.

Comment: That's interesting, we found 2^26-1 to be the limit for indexes so approx 67108863 or lower worked. Strange that an array of doubles is stored as 50 bytes per value?!

Comment: It actually takes around 80 bytes per value in different places in memory :-) But sometimes optimized & takes less.

Comment: Curiously - if values are i32 format is there less memory? This is really interesting stuff, well worth the +upvotes if people have read this far ^_^